# IOS JSON get all values from a "JSON Dict"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

i have this data structure :

```
{ 
  "artistlist " : [ 
                    {
                      "performer" : "Gate Zero"
                    },
                    {
                      "performer" : "nightech"
                    },
                    {
                      "performer" : "Marko Fuerstenberg"
                    },

                  ] 
   }
```

I read this structure from NSString into NSDictionary with this line of code:

```
   JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
   [[chunks objectAtIndex:1]        
   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:              
   NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

with:   `[JSON objectForKey:@"artistlist "]` i get this structure:

```
(
    {
    performer = "Gate Zero";
},
    {
    performer = nightech;
},
    {
    performer = "Marko Fuerstenberg";
}
)
```

Is there any way to go "deeper" ?

how would i parse the resulting Structure ?

I would like to get a list of values or access performer names directly. What if i have several values in a tupel for example performer name, album, year.  How would i access those values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, after you have `[JSON objectForKey:@"artistlist "]`, you get an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` (slightly confusing!).

```
NSArray *performersArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"artistlist"];  
for (NSDictionary *performerDic in performersArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [performerDic objectForKey:@"performer"]);
}
```

This should yield each performer name. Alternatively, you can do `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [performersArray count]; i++)` and access `NSDictionary *performersDic = [performersArray objectAtIndex: i]`. From there, you can similarly use `[performsDic objectForKey:@"performer"]`

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
[[[JSON objectForKey:@"artistlist "] objectAtIndex: 1] objectForKey:@"performer"]
```

It will give you `"nightech"`.

`{}` corresponds to `NSDictionary`, `[]` corresponds to `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use recursion. For example, assuming you have only nested NSDictionaries (easy to modify to work with NSArrays):

```
- (void) getArtistFromJsonObject:(NSDictionary *)obj {
    for (NSString *key in [obj allKeys]) {
        id child = [obj objectForKey:key];
        if ([child isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            // that's the actual string
            // NSLog(@"Found artist: %@", child); // or do whatever needed

        } else if ([child isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [self getArtistFromJsonObject:child];
        }
    }
}
```