# how to store that json data into array, after using jsonserialization iam getting that data

Tags: ios, swift

```
let jsonResult1:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(da!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary

println(jsonResult1)
```

getting below data in console

```
{
    0 =     {
        "consulting_dr" = "DR.Appaji .";
        "current_bed_nr" = 0;
        "current_room_nr" = 0;
        "discharge_date" = "03/03/2015 00:00";
        "encounter_date" = "02/03/2015 12:45";
        "encounter_nr" = 201503024000;
        info = "";
        "item_description" = "";
        name = "Mrs. mythily S";
        pdob = "01/08/1976";
        pid = 100004;
        psex = f;
        pyear = "38 Years";
    };
    1 =     {
        dosage = 1;
        drdate = "25/08/2014";
        drnotes = "";
        drugclass = Tablet;
        duration = "5 day";
        frequency = "";
        medicine = "ACECLOFENAC+PARACETAMOL";
        route = Oral;
        tcomplients = "";
    };
    2 =     {
        BMI = "A:1:{s:4:\"SPO2\";s:1:\"1\";}";
        BSA = "A:1:{s:4:\"SPO2\";s:1:\"1\";}";
        "Dystolic_bp" = 29;
        Height = 24;
        Pulse = 26;
        Respiration = 27;
        "Systolic_bp" = 28;
        Temp = 25;
        Weight = 22;
        dosage = 1;
        drdate = "25/08/2014";
        drnotes = "";
        drugclass = Tablet;
        duration = "5 day";
        frequency = "";
        medicine = RABEPRAZOLE;
        route = Oral;
        tcomplients = "";
    };
}
```

how to store this in array

Comment: This is not a correct json format.

Comment: [Try this][1]
I hope it will be useful for you.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750078/ios-json-get-all-values-from-a-json-dict

Comment: i missed typing  front before 0 { is tere and at end  } is tere

Comment: What you have is a `NSDictionary`, of `NSDictionaries`, not JSON. `da` was JSON. Now you want o to convert it to an array but you need to explain what you want as a result. You also need to try something and if that does not work add that to the question along with why it is not working.

Comment: how to convert this dictionary to json

Comment: hope u understood my question

Comment: how to convert that dictionary to json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a Dictionary. It is easy to get just the data without the keys.
In Objective-C it would be :

```
NSArray *allData = [jsonResult1 allValues];
```

For swift it should be like: (not sure about syntax)

```
var allData = jsonResult1.allValues()
```

Comment: working but   after printing getting  optional and () are getting how to remove this     example:Optional(DR.Appaji .)

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand your qestion. You wanted all values in an array and I understand that your original question is solved. Please mark this question as solved if so.  If there is another question feel free to open a new question.

Comment: println(allData[0]["consulting_dr"])
                
                println(allData[0]["pid"])                console getting           Optional(DR.Appaji .)
Optional(100004)

Comment: i want to remove optional keyword and braces

Comment: Serialize it from json with mutable branches and leaves. This will allow you to modify, eg add and remove, every key or value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for it, you should give SwiftyJSON a try.

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

I've recently used it for an application that deals with a ton of JSON responses from a web service and SwiftyJSON has made it super easy for me to deal with JSON data in Swift. It will convert NSData to Dictionaries or Arrays seamlessly for you.